# How to have multiple labels on one line in Electron Menu

Tags: electron

I'm working in electron and am trying to emulate Chromes 3dot menu and I want to implement in this menu something like the Zoom line. However I can't find in the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu) anything regarding this. I've also searched online but can't find anything related to this saddly.

If anyone has any idea if this is or isn't possible and how this could be accomplished please let me know. I'd prefer to use Electron.menu if at all possible.

Three Dot Menu:

[image: Three Dot Menu]

***Note*** Running Electron 1.8.7 for now going to be upgrading to Electron 3.x in the future if that makes a difference. I'm also using Vue 2.X and Bootstrap 4 if any of that is somehow applicable.

Comment: Don't know what a "Chrome 3dot menu" is. A screenshot image would be helpful.

Comment: Updated question, in the top right of chrome the three dots that when you click give you a menu hence three dot menu